ORA-00939: too many arguments for function, Im using cx_oracle in pycharm to pull from database, and encountering this error below:
the length of the variable hour is 792 and the uitid is 15, so both under 1000, so I don't know why I recieve this error, I tried it two ways as it can be seen below:
first way:

def generate_sql_in_binds(
    name: str,
    size: int,
    start: int = 1,
    max_binds: int = 1000,
) -> str:
    in_clauses = (
        "{name} IN ({binds})".format(
            name=name,
            binds=",".join(
                (
                    f":{b+start}"
                    for b in range(i, min(i+max_binds,size))
                )
            )
        )
        for i in range(0, size, max_binds)
    )
    return "(" + (" OR ".join(in_clauses)) + ")"


and the error is 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


Don't forget to update to the latest cx_Oracle driver - you are a couple of years out of date. The driver got renamed: see the release announcement.

You need to put TO_DATE in the iterator that generates the bind parameters so that it wraps each bind parameter (rather than trying to wrap the entire list):
query = """SELECT HOUR, UNITSCHEDULEID, VERSIONID, MINRUNTIME
FROM  int_Stg.UnitScheduleOfferHourly
WHERE Hour in ({hour_binds})
AND   UnitScheduleId in ({id_binds})""".format(
  hour_binds=",".join(
    (f"TO_DATE(:{idx}, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24')" for idx in range(1, len(hour) + 1))
  ),
  id_binds=",".join(
    (f":{idx}" for idx in range(len(hour) + 1, len(unitid) + len(hour) + 1))
  ),
)
res = connection.cursor().execute(query, (*hour, *unitid)).fetchall()
print(res)

However, you would probably be better to leave the query as it is and convert the list of strings to a list of datetimes.
from datetime import datetime

hour_dt = tuple(datetime.strptime(value, "%d-%b-%Y %H") for value in hour)

query = """SELECT HOUR, UNITSCHEDULEID, VERSIONID, MINRUNTIME
FROM  int_Stg.UnitScheduleOfferHourly
WHERE Hour in ({hour_binds})
AND   UnitScheduleId in ({id_binds})""".format(
  hour_binds=",".join(
    (f":{idx}" for idx in range(1, len(hour_dt) + 1)),
  ),
  id_binds=",".join(
    (f":{idx}" for idx in range(len(hour_dt) + 1, len(unitid) + len(hour) + 1)),
  ),
)

res = connection.cursor().execute(query, (*hour_dt, *unitid)).fetchall()
print(res)


Much Thank you again! small problem was the format in second code had to be changed to "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M" otherwise I had format does not match error, but after changing it I have:  (datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 19, 5, 0), 8006210199, 1, 2.0),
(datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 19, 6, 0), 8006210199, 1, 2.0)

How would you modify this code to take more than 1000 records ?

@arshamvosoughinia Use the generate_sql_in_binds function and pass in datetime values.

I added the generate_sql_in_binds and  this :    hour_binds=generate_sql_in_binds("hour", len(hour_dt))     but it still doesnt work!

I appreciate if you show me how

@MTO I get 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

@arshamvosoughinia Then don't have None values in your lists; that appears to be a data problem and not a code problem. If you think otherwise then ask a new question and provide a [MRE] with the python code you are using and an example of the data that is causing that error so that we can replicate the issue.
